# Sencha fill tab from JSON record

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

My JSON file:

```
{
    "options":{
        "someString": "SomeText",
        "someNumber": 42,
        "someCombo": 2,
        "someBool" : true
    }
}
```

I made a JSON store for that JSON file, it loads correctly.

Now, my options tab:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: {
            align: 'stretch',
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        title: 'Options Tab',
        tabConfig: {
            xtype: 'tab',
            flex: 1
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: 'someString',
                fieldLabel: 'Some String:',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                id: 'someNumber',
                fieldLabel: 'Some Number',
            },
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                id: 'someCombo',
                fieldLabel: 'Some Combo',
                editable: false,
                store: [['0','Option Zero'],['1','Option One'],['2','Option Two']]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                id: 'someBool',
                fieldLabel: 'Some Boolean',
                boxLabel: 'Yes'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

After quite some tries, I did not yet find a way to fill the form elements with JSON data:

```
onJsonstoreLoad: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
    // this.child("#sepString").update(store.getAt(0).fields.getByKey("sepString"));
    // Ext.fly("someString").update(store.getAt(0).fields.getByKey("someString"));
    // Ext.fly("someString").setValue(store.getAt(0).fields.getByKey("someString"));
    Ext.fly("someString").value=store.getAt(0).fields.getByKey("someString");
    ...
    Ext.fly("someBool").checked=store.getAt(0).fields.getByKey("someBool");
}
```

So how do I get data into the form elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`FormPanel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel) and its [`loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) method. You should give a look to [`Ext.form.Basic#setValues`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-setValues) too.

```
var formPanel = Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'form', // Use form xtype instead of panel
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    title: 'Options Tab',
    tabConfig: {
        xtype: 'tab',
        flex: 1
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        // We need names, not ids
        name: 'someString',
        fieldLabel: 'Some String:',
    },{
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        name: 'someNumber',
        fieldLabel: 'Some Number',
    },{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'someCombo',
        fieldLabel: 'Some Combo',
        editable: false,
        store: [['0','Option Zero'],['1','Option One'],['2','Option Two']]
    },{
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        name: 'someBool',
        fieldLabel: 'Some Boolean',
        boxLabel: 'Yes'
    }]
});

// Create a mock record
var MyRecord = Ext.define(null, {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,fields: ['someString', 'someNumber', 'someCombo', 'someBool']
});
var record = new MyRecord({
    "someString": "SomeText",
    "someNumber": 42,
    "someCombo": 2,
    "someBool" : true
});

// You would use the record loaded in your store instead:
//     var record = store.getAt(0);

// In recent version of Ext4, you can call formPanel.loadRecord directly
formPanel.getForm().loadRecord(record);
```

Comment: I am working with sencha architect and I am not able to use `formPanel = Ext.widget()`. How would I access the FormPanel in such a way that I can use `getForm()`? Setting id `optionsForm` on the FormPanel and using `Ext.fly("optionsForm").getForm()` results in an error ("has no method getForm").

Comment: `Ext.fly` grabs a DOM element, not the Ext component. Use [`Ext.getCmp`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp) instead.